# Bash: decode string with url escaped hex codes

Tags: bash, hex, escaping, decode

I am `curl`-ing webpage titles, some of them contain escaped characters (HEX code?), most likely coming from Wordpress `esc_url()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/

```
# title=$(curl -s $theurl | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | tail -c+8)
title='Questions &#038; Answers'
touch $title'.txt'
```

How can I UN-escape or decode these back, without having to make a list and replace them

```
&#038; = Ampersand
&#8217; = Right Single Quotation Mark
&#x2d; = Hyphen-Minus
...
```

Comment: It's pretty hard in pure bash without a list, consider a one line perl: `echo "Questions &#038; Answers" | perl -C -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_);'`

Comment: Thanks! How come this does not work? `title='Questions &#038; Answers'
titleclean=$title | perl -C -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_);'
print $titleclean`

Comment: You need to break the perl enclosures: `title='Questions &#038; Answers' titleclean=$title | perl -MHTML::Entities -le 'print decode_entities("'"$titleclean"'")'`

Comment: thanks again David, I also managed to get it with `titleclean="$(echo "$title" | perl -C -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_)')"` but I need to study the Perl options better.

Comment: your snippet `titleclean=$title | perl -MHTML::Entities -le 'print decode_entities("'"$titleclean"'")'`does seem to get me a new line though...

Comment: You forget the `title='Questions &#038; Answers'` part